# Parse Date From Angular $HTTP API GET call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

Maybe a stupid one but I have been trying different things to get that sorted. I'm parsing a date from a HTTP GET call however when I get the response in the $http -> then function it appears that the date is a plain string so that calls to getDate(), getMonth() etc won't work.

My question then is: do I need to do `new Date(myDateReceived)` every single time or can Javascript be somehow clever enough to detect that the string is actually a date?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you need to use the `Date` constructor every time.

Comment: An alternative, is to intercept any call from $http, and apply a custom parser that detect the dates, and transform the string to a new Date(string).

Answer (score 0):

## It is not.

According to [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype) you can't (or shouldn't) edit the prototype of string to make your string "smarter".